# Android Development: Regarding the usage of shared preferences

Tags: java, android

I read through the guide on the android development for storage options and I was wondering which storage option to use in certain cases. I understand that shared preferences is used to store key-value pairs for primitive information. But what if I have a list of 100, 300, 500, 1000 items? Is it still advisable / possible to use shared preferences? Would it affect performance?

The guide I read was:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no security concern with data, data is `complex` type and data is in large amount I think `SQLite` is the best for it. [SQLiteLink](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)

And if the data is small, data is `premitive` type and you don't want to share it with user then `SharedPreference` is good.

Choice is yours.

Comment: Thanks Ryderz. But that's the thing, data is large and primitive

Comment: you won't have any major problems with a large amount of data in your Shared Prefs. You could, however, have performance issues since the single Shared Pref XML file will have to be read to get any pref while with a database you only have to grab what you need as you need it.

Comment: go through this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/uWhEPF6gzZA